# Xcode 11.3 crashes on launch in macOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina

I've updated my mac to Catalina 10.15 so I can install and work with the latest Xcode version. After installing the software from the App Store, when I click to start it, but it crashes and shows this error message:

> **Loading a plug-in failed:** The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.

I checked the console and I found:

> Legacy client com.apple.dt.Xcode connecting to modern client. You can't mix modern clients with legacy clients. ClientConnect: 0x00007fedb3577170 identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode pid: 773 type: Application>

And the System.log says:

> Dec 20 00:38:08 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Xcode.837): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.SymbolicateXPCService.xpc, error = 129: The service was superseded by a later version
>   Dec 20 00:38:09 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Can you please tell me what's wrong? and how to solve that so I can run Xcode on my Mac?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: @shim Yes, several times. Do you know what the Console message mean?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Xcode installed? Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Could also be a keychain issue — when Xcode launches it wants to install additional components. You could try locking and unlocking your keychain and/or repairing disk permissions and restarting.

Comment: @shim I don't have any other version of xcode and I've already tried restarting, what keychain should I try locking and unlocking? I have a big list of keys

Comment: I meant the entire login keychain

Comment: @shim I tried locking/unlocking the login keychain, repairing the disk, restarting several times, but the issue still exist :(

Comment: Try xcode-select —install’ (my phone is converting the two dashes into an em dash) in terminal

Comment: @shim check the post update, I found that message in the system.log, is that means there's another xcode version in my mac? because I'm sure I deleted it before.

Comment: Looks like specifically complaining about XPCService

Comment: @shim So, what should I do?

Comment: What version of Xcode were you updating from?

Comment: @shim I had Xcode 9.2 in MacOS high sierra, so I installed macOS Catalina in a new disk partition, then I've installed Xcode 11.3 on it.

Comment: This can be caused by a mismatch between your Catalina version and your Xcode version. What versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the date of your Mac as October 1st, 2019.

After components has been installed, change the date to current again.

Comment: It seem's like a cache issue. Try this topic https://superuser.com/questions/1146491/what-is-the-com-apple-dt-xcode-bundle-and-can-i-delete-it